# Sqlite stops using index if query contains concatenation syntax "||"

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

This is a query plan for a regular LIKE query. It uses an index as it should:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=on;
sqlite> explain query plan select * from users where login like 'username%' limit 10;
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH users USING INDEX login_index (login>? AND login<?)
```

This is a query plan for the same query, but that uses concatenation `||` syntax:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=on;
sqlite> explain query plan select * from users where login like 'username' || '%' limit 10;
QUERY PLAN
`--SCAN users
```

**The same query doesn't use an index and switches to scanning whole table.**

The reason I want to use concatenation `||` syntax is because otherwise username won't be recognized as a parameter, i.e. `select * from users where login like '?1%' limit 10` doesn't work - sqlite considers that query has 0 parameters.

Comment: it is programmed that way. but  i don't understand why the query returns 0 rows https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fd6be5d7b019f4b51d5fd485d564e578  can you add a sample of data that shows the proplem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal, documented behavior. The [`LIKE` optimization](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html#the_like_optimization) has a lot of rules and caveats about when it can be used; among them:

> The right-hand side of the LIKE or GLOB must be either a string literal or a parameter bound to a string literal that does not begin with a wildcard character.

You're using an expression.

What you can try is appending the `%` to the end of the string you're binding to the parameter in the code that prepares and executes the query, not in the SQL statement: `login LIKE ?`, with `username%` as that parameter.